# Google Plus one button doesn't works in Magento 1.6

Tags: magento, prototype, google-plus

From today I am facing the weird issue. My PDP page is not loading completely. I am getting "Site is unresponsive" pop up showing error in `js/prototype/prototype.js:347`. In my PDP page, I have integrated GPlus one button. If I comment rendering of this button it works fine. I don't know if Google has updated any API library. I am using https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js to render this button.

Answer (score 0):

I've been experiencing the same issue for about 48 hours. Seems like plusone.js conflicts somehow with prototype.js (or, some of its versions).

UPDATE: after updating prototype.js to 1.7.2 all seems to work.